# Image Shaping Issues: Three dimensional image

Tags: image, neural-network, reshape, shapes, opencv, python

I have an image that is 7 x 5 in length and width, but the image shape is apparently (7,5,3).

When I resize the image to 28 x 28, the shape becomes (28, 28, 3).
I need the shape the be (1, 28, 28), but I have no idea how to do this.

```
image = cv2.imread(importedImage)
image = cv2.resize(image, (28, 28))
image = img_to_array(image)
image = np.array(image, dtype="float32")/ 255.0

print(image)


q = loaded_model.predict(np.array([image]))[0]
```

Reshaping doesn't seem to help.

The printed version of the image is:

```
[[[1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]

 ...

 [[1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]]
  ...
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]

 [[1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  ...
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]]
```

The error is: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 28, 28, 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That extra dimension (the 3) is because OpenCV (and most other package that deal with images) keep separate color channels for Red, Green, and Blue. (OpenCV orders them Blue, Green, Red.) Some images have an "alpha" channel, in which case you'd see (height, width, 4).

You can get to (height, width, 1) by combining the three color channels into one grayscale channel.

```
image = cv2.imread(importedImage)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
resized = cv2.resize(gray, (28, 28))
```

should get you close to what you need.